# How to implement two listview in ListActivity?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I know that when you want to use ListActivity it requires you to put list name in XML as "@android:id/list". In that case if I want to use two listview, how could I implement since it have the same id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A listactivity with `'@android:id/list'` means a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen.
If you want to use two listviews in your activity, you have to use different ids for them. Like:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <ListView   android:id="@+id/list1" 
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                </ListView>
                <ListView   android:id="@+id/list2" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```